# Is it more efficient to separate large and small related data in a SQL table's column?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database table that has a column of type varchar(386). I chose this number of characters because I counted the characters of the longest entry beforehand. I have 400,000 entries currently, but it is expected to increase with time.

I ran a few tests and found out that about 390,000 entries only use 60 or less characters whereas the last 10,000 entries use up to 386 characters.

Should I separate the 10,000 large entries into a separate table? How would I go about implementing that? Would this increase my querying speed efficiency in the long run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VARCHAR` is stored inline with the table. `VARCHAR` is faster when the size is reasonable, the tradeoff of which would be faster depends upon your data and your hardware, you'd want to benchmark a realworld scenario with your data.

The effective maximum number of bytes that can be stored in a `VARCHAR` or `VARBINARY` column is subject to the maximum row size of `65,535 bytes`, which is shared among all columns.

For example, a `VARCHAR(255)` column can hold a string with a maximum length of 255 characters. Assuming that the column uses the latin1 character set (one byte per character), the actual storage required is the length of the string (L), plus one byte to record the length of the string. For the string `'abcd'`, `L` is `4` and the storage requirement is five bytes. If the same column is instead declared to use the `ucs2` double-byte character set, the storage requirement is 10 bytes: The length of 'abcd' is eight bytes and the column requires two bytes to store lengths because the maximum length is greater than 255 (up to `510 bytes`).

For larger data, consider using `TEXT` or `BLOB`. `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns are implemented differently in the `NDB` storage engine, wherein each row in a `TEXT` column is made up of two separate parts. One of these is of fixed size `(256 bytes)`, and is actually stored in the original table. The other consists of any data in excess of `256 bytes`, which is stored in a hidden table. The rows in this second table are always `2,000 bytes` long. This means that the size of a `TEXT` column is `256` if `size <= 256` (where size represents the size of the row); otherwise, the size is `256 + size + (2000 – (size – 256) % 2000)`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

Depends on your database relation, if you rarely using that fields in query. For example for additional info. Create separated table is good options (normalize).

**NOTES :** `VARCHAR` is different with `CHAR`. If you create `VARCHAR(250)` and insert just `20` characters on it then it will take `5 bytes` + `L` different with `CHAR(250)`, it will take `250 bytes` + `L` for same condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the field is a varchar(386) doesn't mean it takes up that much space for every row. If most of your date is 60 characters or less, then those records will only use 60 or less characters for that column.

I think you're safe leaving that column in your table if that make sense for your logical data model.

Comment: That's not true. Most modern DBMS's use a clustered index to quickly determine the records physical location (which would be fixed size). They attempt to store the physical data in a space efficient way to maximize the benefits of caching data pages.

Comment: In any event, in MySQL variable length columns are NOT padded in the data pages. Just don't include the field in a clustered index and you'll be fine.