# What is more efficient to use for a column in a large MySQL table -TINYTEXT or VARCHAR?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, varchar, tinytext

When I have a very large database MySQL table and I wish to add a small text field column that will be rarely used (used only for a small number of records), is it more efficient to use VARCHAR(255) or TINYTEXT?

I am guessing that since TINYTEXT is stored outside of the table (and there is a penalty to access that space), in my case it will be okay, because that penalty be utilized rarely.

Using VARCHAR will place text storage inside the table and affect entire table by storing mostly empty values and utilizing space (?).  So VARCHAR may not be a good choice for me.

Is this assessment accurate?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28184635/2883328 gives some ideas, to where it goes deeper into the storage techniques as I mentioned above, and also describes using a 2nd table, as was mentioned in the comments below.

Comment: I totally understand the impulse to ask (I have it all the time when faced with decisions like this) but I would be *very* surprised if there weren't existing discussion on this out there that answers the question thoroughly and completely. E.g. when Googling `What is more efficient to use for a column in a large MySQL table -TINYTEXT or VARCHAR?` is nothing there useful? Can you clarify why/how?

Comment: I'd venture to guess that since it's a derivative of `TEXT` that indexing sucks/is nonexistant vs a `VARCHAR`. But that's a guess, I didn't actually look up that information.

Comment: Why not use a different table when the small text field is rarely used?

Comment: Second @RaymondNijland - why not make a second table that FKs back to the original table for when these values are needed?  Should help on storage.

Comment: Research suggests that TEXT* field is implemented in MySQL using fixed 256 storage in the original table, and excess of that is stored in a hidden table separately.  If so, I believe making a 2nd table will be counter-productive, and more labor-intensive, seeing that MySQL implements it for you.  Second table though may be useful... so it's a toss up.